# Combinations and Probability Problems

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> > In a medical experiment involving $50$ patients, $20$ patients are chosen to receive drug X, $20$ patients are chosen to receive drug Y, and $10$ patients are chosen to receive no drug. In how many different ways can the treatments for the $50$ patients be assigned?

I tried this problem and I got $\binom{50}{20} * \binom{30}{20} * \binom{10}{10} = 1.416 \times 10^{21}$. I just want to make sure I have the right idea for this problem.

Comment: That looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

You got it.

Choose 20 of the 50 to receive drug X, 20 of the remaining 30 to receive drug Y, and all of the remaining 10 to receive no drug.
$${50\choose 20}\cdot{30\choose 20}\cdot{10 \choose 10} \\= \frac{50!}{20!30!}\cdot\frac{30!}{20!10!}\cdot\frac{10!}{10!0!} \\ = 1,\!415,\!997,\!888,\!807,\!961,\!859,\!400$$
**Alternatively:** There are $50!$ ways to arrange the patients, but the order within the groups of patients who receive each particular drug (or no drug) is not important; and there are $20!$, $20!$, and $10!$ ways to do each.

$${50\choose 20,20,10} \\ =\frac{50!}{20!20!10!} \\ = 1,\!415,\!997,\!888,\!807,\!961,\!859,\!400$$